# Creating a function to characterise repeated simulations

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, statistics, simulation

I want to create a function which helps characterise the results to some simulations. For the purposes of this post let the simulation function be:

```
example_sim <- function(time=100, npops=5){
  result <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = time, ncol = npops))
  colnames(result) <- LETTERS[1:npops]
  for(i in 1:npops){
    sim <- sample.int(time, time)
    result[,i] <- sim
    result[,i] <- result[,i]*i
  }
  return(result)
}
```

This creates a data frame with varying length and width based on the number of populations (npops) and the time simulated.

I want to create a function which uses the output of such simulations and characterises the mean, variance for each population over an n amount of simulations (nsims).

So far I have managed to get it working for two populations with the following code:

```
library("matrixStats")
library("reshape2")

ensembles <- function(nsims=10, time = 100, npops = 2){
  result_N.A <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = time, ncol = nsims))
  result_N.B <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = time, ncol = nsims))
  for( i in 1:(nsims)){
    simulation_with_2pops <- example_sim(time=100,npops=2)
    result_N.A[,i] <- simulation_with_2pops[,1]
    result_N.B[,i] <- simulation_with_2pops[,2]
  }
  output <- simulation_with_2pops
  for( j in 1:params$ntime){
    output$meanA[j] <- rowMeans(result_N.A[j,])
  }
  for( j in 1:params$ntime){
    output$meanB[j] <- rowMeans(result_N.B[j,])
  }
  for( j in 1:params$ntime){
    output$varA[j] <- rowVars(as.matrix(result_N.A[j,]))
  }
  for( j in 1:params$ntime){
    output$varB[j] <- rowVars(as.matrix(result_N.B[j,]))
  }
  return(output)
} 
ensembles_output<- ensembles(nsims = 10)
ensembles_output
```

To fully implement the function for any number of populations I would need to create another for loop where I create and update the `result_N.A` object. (Presumably called something like `result[i]`.)
I have also thought about creating a 3 dimensional object (time, npops, nsims) and taking a slice of it to calculate the mean and variance but i havent had much success yet.
I am not married for this route and am very open to other recommendations.

Eventually I would like to create a code where the covariance and correlation are also calculated by giving highlighting two populations in the parameters. (for instance population A and population E). If you have any ideas on the implementation i would be very grateful to hear them.

Thank you for considering this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a multidimensional array is a very good idea in this case.

First, you can get the simulations of `example_sim()` much cheaper using `mapply()`. Here an example with `time=10` and `npops=3`. Use the same `set.seed(42)` and parameters and check for yourself.

I use much smaller parameters here so that you can easily check the result in your head.

```
set.seed(42)
sim <- replicate(nsims, mapply(\(time, i) sample.int(time, time)*i, 10, 1:3))

sim
# , , 1
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1   16   27
#  [2,]    5   14   30
#  [3,]   10    8    9
#  [4,]    8    2   12
#  [5,]    2   10   15
#  [6,]    4   20   18
#  [7,]    6    4    3
#  [8,]    9   12    6
#  [9,]    7   18   24
# [10,]    3    6   21
# 
# , , 2
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    3   10   18
#  [2,]    1    8    6
#  [3,]    2    4   12
#  [4,]    6   16    9
#  [5,]   10    6   30
#  [6,]    8    2   15
#  [7,]    4   20   27
#  [8,]    5   14   21
#  [9,]    7   12   24
# [10,]    9   18    3
# 
# , , 3
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]   10    8   18
#  [2,]    8   18    6
#  [3,]    5    6   27
#  [4,]    1   16    3
#  [5,]    7   10   24
#  [6,]    4   12   15
#  [7,]    6   20   30
#  [8,]    2    4    9
#  [9,]    9    2   12
# [10,]    3   14   21
```

Next, I believe you want to gather row-wise statistics across each population column A, B, C, ... . Here you basically want `apply(., MARGINS=1:2, FUN)`. Just for the mean there exists `rowMeans(., dims=2L)`, which is faster.

```
rowMeans(sim, dims=2L)
#           [,1]      [,2] [,3]
#  [1,] 4.666667 11.333333   21
#  [2,] 4.666667 13.333333   14
#  [3,] 5.666667  6.000000   16
#  [4,] 5.000000 11.333333    8
#  [5,] 6.333333  8.666667   23
#  [6,] 5.333333 11.333333   16
#  [7,] 5.333333 14.666667   20
#  [8,] 5.333333 10.000000   12
#  [9,] 7.666667 10.666667   20
# [10,] 5.000000 12.666667   15

apply(sim, 1:2, var)
#            [,1]      [,2] [,3]
#  [1,] 22.333333 17.333333   27
#  [2,] 12.333333 25.333333  192
#  [3,] 16.333333  4.000000   93
#  [4,] 13.000000 65.333333   21
#  [5,] 16.333333  5.333333   57
#  [6,]  5.333333 81.333333    3
#  [7,]  1.333333 85.333333  219
#  [8,] 12.333333 28.000000   63
#  [9,]  1.333333 65.333333   48
# [10,] 12.000000 37.333333  108
```

I'm not sure however, why you use `simulation_with_2pops` for your final output, since it's the result of last iteration of `for (i in 1:nsims)` loop. Anyway, hope this helps you further.

**Note: R >= 4.1 used.**

Comment: Hi Jay Thank so much for your answer. I tried running ur code, but my R doesnt recognise the `\` in `mapply(\(time, i)`. Could this be because of my R's verion or is there something else i am missing?

Comment: Welcome @not.a.hackerman ! Yes definitely just [update R](https://cran.r-project.org/), then it will work. We may abbreviate `function(x)` with `\(x)` recently, you could also use the old writing of course.

Comment: Thanks again Jay, your code worked for the example i put in the question. However it doesnt work with my real simulations sadly. I am using a C++ built function to build those simulations which are quite hard to share on this platform. However the same problem persists with using the `example_sim` function i put in the post. This is what I am trying to do: 
`ensembles <- function(nsims=3, time=12, pops=4){
  for( i in 1:(nsims)){
    sim <- replicate(nsims, mapply(function(time, i) example_sim(time,npops = pops), time, 1:pops))
  }
  return(sim)
}
`

Comment: My output is `integer,12` for all cells. I suspect it is a formatting issue. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @not.a.hackerman Your output seems to be multidimensional, and `mapply` tries to build matrices. Try `Map` instead of `mapply` which trows lists.